# How can I solve "Relation 'a' is not instance of HasOne or BelongsTo." in the laravel?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-5.6

My laravel eloquent like this :

```
$query = ItemDetail::selectRaw('a.item_number, sum(abs(a.quantity)) as "total_quantity"')
              ->from('item_detail as a')
              ->join('items as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.item_number');

if(isset($param['vendor'])) {
    $query = $query->where('b.vendor_id', '=', $param['vendor']);
}

$query = $query->groupBy('a.item_number')
               ->paginate($paged);

return $query;
```

If the query executed, there exist error like this :

```
Relation 'a' is not instance of HasOne or BelongsTo.
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

My item model like this :

```
class Item extends Model
{
    ...
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'vendor_id'
    ];
    public function item_details() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemDetail::class, 'id', 'item_number');
    }
}
```

My item detail model like this :

```
class ItemDetail extends Model
{
    ....
    protected $fillable = [
        'item_number',
        'name',
        'posting_date'
    ];
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'id', 'item_number');
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to be more clear. what is happening after returning $query? what is the code you have to run?

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 No. There exist error like that

Comment: What is your model code? what is your controller code? something let us help you.

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 I had update my question

Comment: first, you need to swap the `id` and `item_number` in both relation while the `item_number` is the **foreign key**

Comment: Why are you manually setting table names and joining when you're using eloquent?

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 I'm still confused about what you mean. Please answer this question in detail

Comment: @apokryfos I tried to delete the relation in both models, but it's the same. Please answer this question in detail

Comment: @apokryfos I use join because I need a condition for `where`

Comment: @SuccessMan can you try `$query = $query->groupBy( DB:raw('a.item_number'))->paginate($paged);`

Comment: @rkj It's the same. It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your few details, please confirm if this is what you want:

**Item Model:**

```
class Item extends Model
{
  ...
  protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'vendor_id'
  ];

  public function item_details() 
  {
      return $this->hasMany(ItemDetail::class, 'item_number', 'id');
  }
}
```

**ItemDetail Model:**

```
class ItemDetail extends Model
{
  ....
  protected $fillable = [
    'item_number',
    'name',
    'posting_date'
  ];

  public function item()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'item_number', 'id');
  }
}
```

**Controller Method:**

```
$itemDetails = ItemDetail::whereHas('item', function($q) use ($param) {
    if (isset($param['vendor']){
        $q->where('vendor_id', '=', $param['vendor']);
    }
})
->selectRaw('item.id', 'item_detail.item_number', 'sum(abs(a.quantity)) as total_quantity')
->groupBy('item_number')->paginate($paged);
```

**View file:**

```
@foreach($itemDetails as $itemDetail)
    @dump($itemDetail->item_number)
    @dump($itemDetail->total_quantity)
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to access the main model you want and include in it, the relationships you need to include.

Here's a potential different solution:

```
$query = Item::with(['item_details' => function ($query) {
    $query->groupBy('item_number')->selectRaw("item_number, sum(abs(a.quantity)) as 'total_quantity'");
}]);
if (isset($param['vendor'])) {
    $query->where('vendor_id', $param['vendor']);
}
$itemsPage = $query->paginate($paged);
return $pages;
```

You can access the paged data if you do:

```
foreach ($itemsPage as $item) {
    // $item is an instance of Item
    // $item->item_details->total_quantity should have the sum of the item details
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess because of too few information: your model is missing something like this:

```
public function a()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(RelatedModel::class);
}
```

Comment: I can't, because I need your models.